# Already at head but still pending push?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have hard reset current master to one commit, but why it still shows 16 to push? is it a bug?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try a fetch: you local state for origin/master might be obsolete.

If not, double-check the state in command-line:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git status
```

And try to close/re-open SourceTree to see if the issue persists.